# flake8 is not picking up the project level config

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I have `setup.cfg` file in the directory containing python files with the following content

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 100
```

Directory structure:

```
project_root
|
|__src
    |
    |__script
        |
        |__ script1.py
        |
        |__ script2.py
        |
        |__ setup.cfg
```

I validate the file by running the following from `project_root` directory:

`flake8 src/script`

The line length config overwrite is not picked up by flake8 i.e. it is validating with the default setting of 79 characters length.

Flake8 version:

```
$ flake8 --version                                                                                                 
3.8.2 (import-order: 0.18.1, mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.6.0, pyflakes:
2.2.0) CPython 3.7.7 on Darwin
```

What am I missing here?

P.S. new to python. pardon me if the question is too basic.

Comment: can you run `ls -al` inside your directory?  I suspect you may also have a `tox.ini` or `.flake8` file

Comment: Checked. No tox.ini or .flake8 file in the directory.

Comment: is your working directory inside `dir`?

Comment: `dir` itself is my working directory.

Comment: maybe try posting with `flake8 -vvv`?  I cannot reproduce your problem at all

Comment: @AnthonySottile my bad. I got confused by the maven build script which was actually triggering the flake8 execution. I have updated the description. The flake8 is triggered from project_root directory.

Comment: put `setup.cfg` in `project_root` then, or use `--config src/script/setup.cfg` or `cd into src/script` before running flake8

Comment: The issue is, that is the structure of a project on which multiple people work. Interestingly other team members are not facing this issue. I am more interested in knowing why it is occurring on my machine only.

Comment: the configuration lookup was simplified in flake8 3.8, they're probably using an old version (I'm the maintainer)